# If no image, show no product: shopify

Tags: image, shopify, product

I think this one is pretty easy but cannot quite wrap my head around it.
Pretty straight forward command, since I am working with no completed database I'd like to show products only if they have at least one image associated with them.

Shortly, I'd need something like: if product doesn't have an image, then hide product.
How would I go about this on Shopify? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way to hide it using the settings. However since Shopify is extensible product. You can write your own plug-in to hide.

Another simple way is it to export your products as CSV. Open it in Excel and set the Hidden column's value based on the Image column's value, such that if Image column is blank Hidden column's value is true. You can use a formula for that.

Once done save the CSV and import it back in to your Shopify.

Comment: Cannot take the CSV route since I have the link to image to all products IMG SRC column. what happens is that the link to image is always there, but some images are not uploaded to Shopify "FILES" resulting in a no image for product.   I'd rather go for a command code hidden in website code itself that hides automatically products who have no images, how can I do that?

Comment: [Take a look here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/products-with-no-images-help-368208) and ask your question on [Shopify University Forum](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion) to get sure-shot answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies so far, I did ask on Shopify forum aswell, however, I see that most of questions get redirected to "contact our Shopify Experts" , like https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/hide-delete-products-that-have-no-image-associated-with-it-368835 )  This is a big reason on why I am asking on other platforms aswell, the whole "helping attitude" seems lost to me on shopify university forum.... more like "another way to advertise our services forum", sorry for the burst. still in needing of help :(